# Call WCF web service that returns Task<classinstance> from Android

Tags: android, .net, wcf, async-await

I have a .NET 4.5 WCF web service which has this code in the interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "UpdCategorieArticoli",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Task<JsonGenericResponse> UpdCategorieArticoli(string jsonData);
```

And is implemented so (in synthesys) :

```
public async Task<JsonGenericResponse> UpdCategorieArticoli(string jsonData)
{
    JsonGenericResponse objWmJson = new JsonGenericResponse();
    objWmJson.IsInError = "true";
    try
    {
        DataIfCloudEspresso objData = new DataIfCloudEspresso();
        string xmlData = <some transformation from json>;
        int intUpdatedCount = await objData.UpdCategorieArticoli(xmlData );
        if (intUpdatedCount == 1)
        {
            objWmJson.IsInError = "false";
            objWmJson.Value = intUpdatedCount.ToString();
        }
        return objWmJson;
    }
}
```

The JsonGenericResponse is a class :

```
public class JsonGenericResponse
{
    string _Value;
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
        }
    }
    .... Other properties
}
```

The called method in the data layer:

```
public async Task<int> UpdCategorieArticoli(string xmlData)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(base.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdADO = new SqlCommand("spUpd_CategorieArticoli", objConn))
            {
                cmdADO.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@XMLDoc", SqlDbType.Text));
                cmdADO.Parameters["@XMLDoc"].Value = xmlData;
                cmdADO.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmdADO.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                //
                cmdADO.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //
                await objConn.OpenAsync();
                await cmdADO.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                return (int)cmdADO.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is called successfully from jQuery and it is working , with a call as

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WEspresso.svc/UpdCategorieArticoli",
    data: strData,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: saveCategorieArticoli_onComplete
});
```

In the callback i can see my json string, based on the JsonGenericResponse class,  as expected.

The problem comes when i try to call this web service from Android.
If i implement a contract as

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "UpdCategorieArticoliSync",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
JsonGenericResponse UpdCategorieArticoliSync(string jsonData);
```

And some fake code in the implementation  if i launch in debug the site from Visual Studio 2012 with a breakpoint  i can see that the method is reached, instead if i try to call the method that returns Task<> the breakpoint in Visual Studio 2012 is not reached from my Android code:

```
public class wsWcfUpdCateg extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/UpdCategorieArticoli";
    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.0.1/CloudTest/wespresso.svc/UpdCategorieArticoli";
public Context maincontext; 
HttpResponse objResponse = null;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);             
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    StringBuilder objString = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        HttpClient objHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(objHttpClient.getParams(), 10000);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        HttpPost objPost = new HttpPost(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        //
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonData", arg0[0].toString()));
        for (NameValuePair p : params){
            json.put(p.getName(), p.getValue());
        }        
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        objPost.setEntity(se);
        objPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        objPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");  
        objResponse = objHttpClient.execute(objPost);              
        StatusLine objStatusLine = objResponse.getStatusLine();
        Integer intStatus = objStatusLine.getStatusCode();              
        //
        return objString.toString() ;    
    }   
}
```

}

In the above code the intStatus is 400 , if i change simply  UpdCategorieArticoli to UpdCategorieArticoliSync instead i get 200 (and the breakpoint in the .NET code is reached).
How to implement the Android code so it can works with a WCF method that returns Task , with JSON as Response format ? Should i use the "sync version" from Android, otherwise no hope ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the service is implemented synchronously or asynchronously. In both cases, it should behave the same from the client's point of view.

Comment: I think the same, but it does not work

Comment: One easy way of testing if Task is responsible is to add another method that's not async and trying to call that one. Does tha twork?